# in R sort row data in ascending order

Tags: r, sorting

I have a matrix in the following format:

```
    M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 S1 S2
V1  14 19 28 43 10  3  4
V7  25 30 24  9 39  8  4
V8  34 39  6 35 19  9  5
```

I want to sort each row[1:5] and then row[6:7] into ascending order to return the following result:

```
      M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 S1 S2
  V1  10 14 19 28 43 3 4
  V7  9  24 25 30 39 4 8
  V8  6  19 34 35 39 5 9
```

I have looked at the stack overflow answers on the sort/order topic, but have found nothing that achieves this result.
Could someone suggest a way forward , please. The colnames and rownames are not important in the result if one cannot move values within a row without the colname having to change with the position of the value.

Comment: I want each row to be in ascending order i.e. M1 to M5 in ascending order and S1 and S2 in ascending order. Each row treated as a separate 'vector'

Comment: probably an effective workaround would be to transpose your matrix using t(matrix) and then sort for each column; after that you transpose back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `matt` is your matrix:

```
cbind(t(apply(matt[,1:5], 1, sort)),t(apply(matt[,6:7], 1, sort)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]   10   14   19   28   43    3    4
[2,]    9   24   25   30   39    4    8
[3,]    6   19   34   35   39    5    9
```

Or using `plyr` for more readability:

```
library(plyr)

f = function(vec) aaply(matt[,vec], 1, sort)
cbind(f(1:5), f(6:7))
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you. Tried apply() previously, but without t(apply(). Many thanks.

Comment: with plyr option you do not have to use the transpose operator !

Answer (score 3):

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text= "    M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 S1 S2
V1  14 19 28 43 10  3  4
V7  25 30 24  9 39  8  4
V8  34 39  6 35 19  9  5", header = TRUE))

t(apply(m, 1, function(x) c(sort(x[1:5]), sort(x[6:7]))))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#V1   10   14   19   28   43    3    4
#V7    9   24   25   30   39    4    8
#V8    6   19   34   35   39    5    9
```

Comment: uff we replied in the same time, but I like the `c` approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data <- matrix(data = c(14, 19, 28, 43, 10, 3, 4, 25, 30, 24, 9, 39, 8, 4, 34, 39, 6, 35, 19, 9, 5), nrow = 3, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE)
```

First I  created a `result` matrix,

```
result <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 7)
```

then for each `my_data`'s row I sorted the first five elements, sorted the 6th and 7th elements, bound it all together and put it all inside the `result` matrix.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_data)) { result[i, ] <- c(sort(my_data[i, 1:5]), sort(my_data[i, 6:7]))}
```