# Sort dataframe with multiple columns for multiple years

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data.frame with multiple columns and first column being Year. I want to sort my data frame in descending order for each year. I have fifteen years of data and then over 3000 columns.

I illustrate as follows:

```
Year    A   B   C   D
2000    2   3   4   NA
2001    3   4   NA  1
```

Desired output, my data frame has `NA`s as well but I can not remove those.

```
Year    C   B   A
2000    4   3   2
Year    B   A   D
2001    4   3   1
```

And this verion as well

```
 Year           
    2000    C   B   A
    2001    B   A   D
```

I have  scripted this code

```
Asc <-order(df[-1], decreasing=True)
```

But I'm unable to obtain my desired output. I have referred [in R sort row data in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067587/in-r-sort-row-data-in-ascending-order) but still its different for what I'm looking for.
Would appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: The desired output may create problems with the `class` of each column.

Comment: @akrun so, each column may have different class?

Comment: In your desired output you are mixing classes within each column which will end up being a character column

Comment: @DavidArenburg okie now I understand does it turn out to be bigger problem because I have to form deciles next.

Comment: You won't be able to convert it a numeric class as long as you have alphabetic character there. Which of the two is your desired output? It's not clear

Comment: @DavidArenburg 1st one as I mentioned need to form deciles from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.  We loop through the rows of the dataset (excluding the first column) with `apply`, get the index of non-NA elements ('i1'), order the non-NA values descendingly ('i2'), and use that to rearrange the column names of the dataset.

```
m1 <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) {
         i1 <- !is.na(x)
         i2 <- order(-x[i1])
         names(df1)[-1][i1][i2]}))
m1
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "C"  "B"  "A" 
#[2,] "B"  "A"  "D"
```

If we need the values and also the `names`, a `list` approach would be more suitable as it won't create any problems in the `class`

```
 lst <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x){
            i1 <- !is.na(x)
           list(sort(x[i1],decreasing=TRUE))})
 lst
 #[[1]]
 #[[1]][[1]]
 #C B A 
 #4 3 2 


 #[[2]]
 #[[2]][[1]]
 #B A D 
 #4 3 1
```

We can extract the `names` or the elements from the 'lst'

```
  do.call(rbind, do.call(`c`,rapply(lst, names, 
             how='list')))
  #   [,1] [,2] [,3]
  #[1,] "C"  "B"  "A" 
  #[2,] "B"  "A"  "D"
```

Or

```
  t(sapply(do.call(c, lst), names))
```

and the values as

```
  t(simplify2array(do.call(c, lst)))
```

Comment: could you please ellaborate this code, so, you have less inconvience from me

Comment: I got a very weird output its a matrix now with 15 elements.

Comment: @Aquarius Based on your example, it is working fine for me.

Comment: True that, I will go through it again.